# how to control div heights of parent when different child div have different height

Tags: html

I designed a page but due to data the layout is not correct

My  parent div height is auto , but different child div have different height and so  layout is screwed
Please see here

Comment: Please show us your CSS and HTML code. and maybe add a fiddle for visualization

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ashusah/8erazymc/

Answer (score 0):

please try using any of the folowing styles to your arent div

```
{
height:<height>px !important;overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

or

```
{
height:<height>px !important;overflow-y:scroll;
}
```